# what is a multiplicative group in prime order p?

Tags: group-theory

on [pg. 378](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQFjAB&url=http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-642-22792-9_21.pdf&ei=_S1cUpreIo3M9gSJm4DAAQ&usg=AFQjCNETeB__C6tMYzm13OqRbUkJoTzbcQ&sig2=r_zaobJABpdvDT0x6P14fA&bvm=bv.53899372,d.eWU) section 2 (Overview) it says "We let G be a [multiplicative group of prime order p](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Group_of_prime_order) , and g be a generator of G. We let e : G x G --> $G_T$" be a [bilinear map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_map).

If somebody could please break each piece of this into smaller parts I would really appreciate it.  Here is my attempt:

G is a multiplicative group in order p.  Since G is cyclic this means any member of G multiplied by any integer mod p yields identity (1).

g being the generator, means that you always start with g.  So you can raise g to a power or you can multiply g by a random integer.  But you always have to get 1 mod p for it to be a member of G.

Before looking at [binlinear map](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.897/spring04/L25.pdf), I thought I should first read what a [linear map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) is.  According to wikipedia, a linear map always yields the same subspace of the input subspaces.  So bilinear I think you can end up with something that is not linear (like an elliptic curve?).

My understanding of all this is quite fuzzy and I would appreciate it if someone could explain these to me in simple English or easy-to-understand drawings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$G$ is not the group of integers mod $p$.

- $G$ is a group, that is a set with a composition that obeys the group axioms.
- it is multiplicative, that is we agree to use $\cdot$ (and not $+$, say) as symbol for the composition
- it s of order $p$, that is its underlying set has $p$ elements
- $g$ is a generator, which im plies that $G$ is cyclic
- $e\colon G\times G\to G_T$ is bilinear, that is for each $a\in G$, the map $G\to G_T$, $x\mapsto e(a,x)$ is linear and $x\mapsto e(x,a)$ is also linear

Comment: What is bilinear then? Did I get that right? Is there an example of a simple bilinear function ?

Comment: Knowing a bit more of the context would be handy. Could it be that $G$ is in fact a subset of some ring, so that the distinction of additive vs. miultiplicative group is not just a notational one?